# Tests don't run in gitlab-ci pipeline

Tags: maven, unit-testing, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have some tests in my project and they don't run in my local system.

Although in my gitlab-ci the test stage was passed completely, the tests don't run.

My test stage is:

```
mvn_test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - mvn $MAVEN_OPTS $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS clean verify -Dmaven.test.skip=false --quiet
    - mvn $MAVEN_OPTS $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS jacoco:report
  artifacts:
    reports:
      junit:
        - "**/target/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml"
    paths:
      - "**/target/site/jacoco"
    expire_in: 1 week
  only:
    - merge_requests
```

And this is my pom.xml file:

[pom file](https://justpaste.it/22imu)

I had to change some names...

what can I do for running all the tests?

Comment: This is defined for `merge_requests` as the script states? Correct location?

Comment: @khmarbaise Sorry I didn't get what you mean. that part will only run when the merge request is made.

Comment: Can you share the (redacted) job output? Otherwise, how do you know they aren't running (just so we can understand what might be happening)?

Comment: @Adam I noticed the problem. My tests are in the submodule.
Actually, I haven't any src folder in my root. Instead, I have a submodule in my project's root which has src/test. and tests are located there.
How can I make GitLab aware of this to starts tests from there?

Comment: For solving the problem, I added `variables:   GIT_SUBMODULE_STRATEGY: recursive` in my gitlab-ci, but the tests didn't run.

Comment: Can you remove all additional parameters and just leave `mvn verify`? What is the output?

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov the output is here: [link](https://justpaste.it/3xuz5) . I had to rename some names.

Comment: `tests are skipped` - I assume your `pom.xml` has configuration which does it.

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov Should I show my pom.xml file to find out why this is happening?

Comment: please add to the question

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov I added the pom file content in the main question.

Comment: your pom skips tests by default - why?

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov oh I didn't notice that part. I removed `<maven.test.skip>true</maven.test.skip`  and `<skipTests>${maven.test.skip}</skipTests>` but the tests still `[INFO] Tests are skipped.`.

Comment: Also, I changed `<maven.test.skip>true</maven.test.skip` to `<maven.test.skip>false</maven.test.skip`, now the tests don't skip but `[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0` show in the console.

Comment: Can you remove whole `<includes>` section from surefire plugin configuration?

Comment: I also suggest you use https://start.spring.io/ to create project template which uses Java, Kotlin, Hibernate etc. This project template will have proper folders structure and pom.xml

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov I removed the `<includes>` section. but the problem still there. when  run the verify, the result is: `[INFO] Results: [INFO]  [INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0`. I'm sorry I bothered you so much. :((

Comment: I used [start.spring.io](https://start.spring.io/)  to create a fresh pom. after replacing the fresh pom, I added some dependencies and plugins which required. but when I run maven verify, the test didn't run again. this is my [new pom file](https://justpaste.it/5x9oh)  and this is the [verify outPut](https://justpaste.it/77ztl)

Comment: does fresh **unmodified** project generated by start.spring.io run tests?

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov the unmodified pom didn't run at all. because the project has some configuration itself and it needs some plugins and dependencies which I had to add in pom. actually, I can't run the pure fresh pom, because of the project requirements.