# Tests are not running in my gitlab-ci pipeline

Tags: maven, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I know that [Tests don't run in gitlab-ci pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66226838/tests-dont-run-in-gitlab-ci-pipeline) seems to look like the question I'm trying to ask. However, my `.gitlab-ci.yml` and `pom.xml` files are almost as generic as you can possibly have them and my tests are not running.

My `.gitlab-ci.yml` looks like this:

```yaml
image: maven:3.8.6-openjdk-18-slim

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - mvn compile
  tags:
    - shared_runner1

test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - mvn clean test
  tags:
    - shared_runner1
```

My `pom.xml` looks like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>simple-project</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>15</source>
                    <target>15</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>5.9.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

and the test results look like this:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Results :
Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  01:00 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-09-21T13:39:08Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

even though I have one class with a test method that is passing. May I please know what is going wrong with my setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. My pom file doesn't have the surefire plugin, which when added would make the file look like:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>comp2120-2022-group-assignment-2</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>15</source>
                    <target>15</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.0</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>5.9.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Comment: Nice job figuring it out. A clarification: the Surefire plugin is available by default, whether or not it is specified in your project's POM. However, the current default plugin version doesn't support JUnit 5. For that, it has to be 2.22.x (as you have it) or one of the 3.x milestone releases. So basically, updating the version of the plugin is what did the trick.